# Is it possible to query historical data from azure event hub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

1. I read that event hub has retention period up to 60days. So is it possible to query the historical data from event hub?
2. Will it delete the processed events automatically? Assuming yes - If not so - what is the point of storing the processed message?

Answer (score 1):

Event Hubs represents a persistent stream of events, meaning that data is not deleted until its retention period is reached.  Once an event is older than the retention period, it is removed from the stream and no longer available to be read.

There is no concept of processed or unprocessed events; readers may request any position in the stream and re-read data as many times as they like.  It is an application's responsibility to track which events they have processed and position readers accordingly.

Event Hubs retention periods vary by tier, the maximum of which is 90 days (premium and dedicated).  Details can be found in [Event Hubs Quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas#basic-vs-standard-vs-premium-vs-dedicated-tiers).  The Event Hubs FAQ adds a bit more detail in [What is the maximum retention period for events?](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#what-is-the-maximum-retention-period-for-events-)

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to query the historical data from event hub?

Adding to **@Jesse Squire**, sure it is possible to capture the historical data from event hubs when you enable Capture while creating the event hub where the data in the event hubs is sent to storage account.

[image]

Results:

[image]